# Open link in new window when clicking on marker

Tags: leaflet, hyperlink

I have my map showing my different markers - from info pulling from MySQL. But I need to let the marker open html when clicked on.

At this moment the popup is just the marker label and does not take you to the link provided.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJC Tracking</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:100%"></div>

    <script src="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>

    <script>

    var planes = [
        ["CM63CKGP",-26.090852,28.137212, "http://ajcdev.savanacloud.com/custom/qsourcescript/leaflet/single.php?Registration=CM63CKGP"],
["CW94GBGP",-26.12728,28.037458, "http://ajcdev.savanacloud.com/custom/qsourcescript/leaflet/single.php?Registration=CW94GBGP"],
["DJ17CSGP",-26.037963,28.115384, "http://ajcdev.savanacloud.com/custom/qsourcescript/leaflet/single.php?Registration=DJ17CSGP"],
            ["Office",-25.6641595,28.2375668]
        ];

        var map = L.map('map').setView([-25.890852, 28.090852], 10);
        mapLink = 
            '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);

        for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
            marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2]])
                .bindPopup(planes[i][0])
                .addTo(map);
        }
        
         function onClick(e) {
        console.log(this.options.win_url);
        window.open(this.options.win_url);
    }
 

  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend updating your leaflet version to 1.7.1 which is the latest, and note that there are differences between leaflet 0.7 and 1+.

About your popup not opening the link, it's because you set the url as text, and not as a link.

You should do this to create a link:

```
marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2]])
            .bindPopup(`<a href="${planes[i][0]}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">whatever text you want to display for your link</a>`)
            .addTo(map);
```

Comment: How do i get each individual marker then to have its own link, sorry stil dont understand how i should change my code. did the upgrade though

Comment: when you just change the `bindPopup` statement you can have your own link. If you want the link to appear as a url just do `.bindPopup(\`<a href="${planes[i][0]}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">${planes[i][0]}</a>\`)`

Comment: thanks working 100% you are a star, one extra question though;

Comment: if i want ${planes[i][0]} to be shown as a label under each marker and still have the popups working? how do i do that

Comment: `bindTooltip(\`${planes[i][0]} \`)` That's the closest leaflet has to a label

Comment: thanks, i had similar but it only shows when you hover over marker - i want it to show permanetly

Comment: thanks you guys rock, it work 100%